# How can I implement ClientLogin on Android to access Google services?

Tags: android

What is a good way to implement the Google ClientLogin scheme below on Android?

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html

My understanding is that Android does not support the GData API. So I wanted to say, login to my Google books account, will I be able to do it using Android and the reference above? What classes should I be looking at in the Android SDK? (I am using Android 1.6.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do; you can use the standard Java networking and built-in Apache Commons HTTP client library to make the HTTP requests.

You just implement the required requests, though note that you may need to handle the display of a CAPTCHA if Google asks you to.

As there are a few OAuth implementations for Android already, you could also try looking at Google's [OAuth authentication mechanism](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuthForInstalledApps.html) — but it actually looks more complex and not as seamless...

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Sorry I didn't see you specifically requested the ClientLogin scheme, which seems to be deprecated. Any strong reason why you would want to use that and not OAuth?

Yes, you can. I've written an OAuth Java implementation ([Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/)) which does exactly that. We use it in Qype Radar so users can connect Radar with their Qype accounts without the app having to remember usernames and passwords.

It also works with the Google Web services, I've tested that.

Comment: I don't know too much about ClientLogin vs OAuth, but will read up. Thanks for the tip.